# How to use localization in Laravel+Vue app

Tags: laravel, vue.js, localization

I'm trying to make a website using Larave+Vue. So I want to use two languages in there, but I don't know how to use Localization in the Laravel+Vue mix application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need  default [Laravel localization](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/localization) + [Vue Localization](https://kazupon.github.io/vue-i18n/)